# Using where regexp with colum name

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

```
SELECT
    m.id as m_id, s.id as s_id
FROM
    table1 as m, table2 as s
WHERE
    s.id = 123 AND
    lower(s.body) REGEXP CONCAT('\\b',lower(m.name),'\\b')
```

With this MySQL query, I want to use `m.name` with `regexp` but it does not work. The error is: Syntax error in regular expression on line 1, character 3. In MySQL 5.7, it works with `[[:<:]]`. However, the same query does not work with `\\b` in MySQL 8.

Comment: Are there any special characters in `m.name`?

Comment: Does it work if you just use `lower(s.body) REGEXP lower(m.name)`? I know it won't return the desired results, I just want to know if it gets the same error.

Comment: @Barmar There are nearly 1000 rows in table1. All names have alphabetic characters but some of them has '.

Comment: @Barmar If I only give m.name it says: Error in query (3688): Syntax error in regular expression on line 1, character 1.

Comment: At least one of the names starts with a character that has a special meaning in regular expressions, like `*` or `+`.

Comment: I checked and there is no name that includes `*` or `+`. But some names has `-` and `'`.

Comment: Same query works with same data in MySQL 5.7 and `[[:<:]]`.

Comment: Neither of those should cause a problem. But the error message is very clear. Try `SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(name, 1) FROM table1;` to see all the different first characters.

Comment: They have different regexp engines, so the new engine may be sensitive to different characters.

Comment: I run the LEFT query and there are rows with `@` and `{`. I think they are the cause of the errors. Should I run REPLACE in concat?

Comment: The `{` character is the problem.

Comment: `LOWER(REPLACE(m.name, '{', ''))` should solve the problem.

Comment: But there might be other mistakes, so that may not be a complete solution.

Comment: BTW, MySQL 8.x adds a `REGEXP_LIKE()` function that has an `i` flag to make it case insensitive.

Comment: I can use REGEXP_LIKE. Thanks. Since the main problem is solved I can fix the remaining parts.